I am encountering this message "expression must have a constant value"
This was my class assignment and it's running fine but I encounter this message

expression must have a constant value

I am using VS Code. How can I correct it?
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int n, m;
    printf("Enter the no.of rows ");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    printf("Enter the no.of columns ");
    scanf(" %d", &m);

    int arr[n][m];

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter element a[%d][%d] ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("The matrix is\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

Code on VScode

You need to compile with the C standard set to at least C99.  You can't have variable-length arrays (VLAs) in C90 mode.  And int arr[n][m]; is a VLA.

You should check that both n > 0 m > 0 and that they are reasonable size otherwise your program will segfault when running out of stack space.

For GCC you can use option -std=c99 to select a standard version that is a bit more recent than ancien C90. It will allow you to use VLA.

The message "expression must have a constant value" that you're encountering in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) is likely because of the way you're declaring the array arr[n][m] with variable sizes for its dimensions. In standard C (specifically C90), the size of arrays must be known at compile time, and thus they must be constant. However, n and m are variables that get their values at runtime through user input, which makes arr[n][m] a variable-length array (VLA). One way to resolve it is using Dynamic Memory Allocation.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, m;
    printf("Enter the no.of rows ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the no.of columns ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("Enter element a[%d][%d] ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix is\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Free the allocated memory
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}


Make sure you explain what you are doing and why.

BTW: no need to cast malloc in C. (int *)malloc(... -> malloc(...
